# How can I return text to my current mvc view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a login page within an ASP.NET Core App with a pop up to send a password reset email to the users email (Just using Identity):

```
<div class="login-body">
<div class="container">
    <form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" method="post" class="form-signin">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">@Localizer["Sign In"]</h2>
        <div class="login-wrap">
            <div class="user-login-info">
                <input asp-for="Email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="@Localizer["Email"]" autofocus/>
                <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                <input asp-for="Password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="@Localizer["Password"]"/>
                <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input asp-for="RememberMe"/> Remember me
                <span class="pull-right">
                    <a data-toggle="modal" href="#forgotPassModal">Reset Password</a>
                </span>
            </label>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-login btn-block" type="submit">@Localizer["Sign In"]</button>

            <div class="registration">
                @Localizer["No Account"]
                <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register">@Localizer["Create Account"]</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="forgotPassModal" class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Reset Password</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Enter your e-mail address below to reset your password.</p>
                        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="off" class="form-control placeholder-no-fix">

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Cancel</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-success" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="ForgotPassword" method="post">Submit</button>
                            @*<input type="button" class="btn btn-success" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="ForgotPassword" formmethod="post">Submit<input>*@
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- modal -->
    </form>
</div>
```

When I input the email address it does the right thing, sends an email with a code, but it redirects me to a separate view stating to go check your emails.

Is it possible to just return a message either to the popup window or login page saying the same thing?

This is the ForgotPassword Action:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
            if (user == null || !(await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user)))
            {
                return View("ForgotPasswordConfirmation");
            }
           var code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
           var callbackUrl = Url.Action(nameof(ResetPassword), "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: HttpContext.Request.Scheme);
           await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(model.Email, "Reset Password",
           $"Please reset your password by clicking here: <a href='{callbackUrl}'>link</a>");
           return View("ForgotPasswordConfirmation");
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can use is TempData. TempData can hold data for one more additional request and only for one additional request. So you can store this information in the TempData. It is meant for things like your use case. It could look something like this.

```
public IActionResult Login()
{
    var loginModel = new LoginModel();
    loginModel.ForgotPassWordModel = (ForgotPassWordModel) TempData["ForgotPassword"];
    return View(loginModel);
}

public IActionResult ForgotPassword()
{
    if (valid)
    {
        TempData["ForgotPassword"] = new ForgotPassWordModel() {callbackUrl = "Go to this"};
        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }
    return View();
}
```

Here is my example LoginModel and my ForgottonPasswordModel. Ofcourse, yours will be more complicated.

```
public class ForgotPassWordModel
{
    public string callbackUrl;
}

public class LoginModel
{
    public ForgotPassWordModel ForgotPassWordModel { get; set; }
}
```

When someone makes a request to ForgotPassword, if it is valid, store the result in TempData and Redirect back to Login. Now you can read the TempData["ForgotPassword"] that you just set in the previous request. In my example, I put the data in my LoginModel. If there is no tempData, it would be null. Now in your view you can check for this ForgotPassword property.

```
@if (Model.ForgotPassWordModel != null)
{
    // Show message/modal
}
```

The great thing about TempData is that when you set data, it is only held for one more additional request so it works for situations like these.